# Can SharePoint workflow reference a table/list

Tags: workflow

I realize this question is a bit vague, but I am trying to get a general idea of what is possible.  I am using SharePoint online. I will have a large list (may or may not be in SharePoint) of markets.  Associated with each market will be 3 people. The data in this list may change often. I am trying to determine if it is possible to create a work flow that sends an email to each of the 3 people associated with the market indicated when a new item is created.  Or would all of the market/email data have to be incorporated within the workflow code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's entirely possible with SharePoint Designer. You will need to set the "on Workflow Created", then determine the "market" field that was entered, and use that to cross reference to another list that has the associated people to each market, and grab their email addresses. Use that email address and use a send an email action to send the email with whatever data you want to display in their email.